# Django Queryset: Filter for subset of many to many relation

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

Let's assume the following model:

```py
class User(models.Model):
     clients = models.ManyToManyField(Client)
```

How to query users by a list of clients, so that only those users are returned that have **not other** clients than those in the given list assigned.

```
User.objects.filter(client__??=[client1, client2])
```

I had a look at [Django's documentation of field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups), but that did not help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this needs to be done with sql `EXCEPT` which can be accessed by `queryset.difference()`

So the idea is take "ALL" Users and remove the ones that match your clients query.

```
User.objects.all().difference(User.objects.filter(clients__in=excluded_clients))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
clients = [client1, client2]  # this is a list but most probably it will be a queryset, it works either way

users = []
for client in clients:
     users += client.users.all()
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: @beikeni i like the idea, but that will get quite unperformant with thousands of clients. Looking for a solution that solves that on ORM/DB level.